# ASP.NET OnTextChanged Event Not Responding Instantly

Tags: javascript, asp.net

It is working but it is not responding instantly. When I click somewhere it is working.

I also tried the `onkeyPress` technique:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtWriter" runat="server" onkeyPress="txtOnKeyPress"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

But I am receiving a message like:

> Attribute 'onkeyPress' is not a valid attribute of element 'TextBox'.

Comment: What happens if you move the attribute assignment to the code-behind, i.e.: `txtWriter.Attributes["onkeypress"] = "txtOnKeyPress()";`?

Answer (score 3):

Which version of ASP.NET? The following certainly works for me<sup>*</sup>:

```
<script>
    function txtOnKeyPress() {
        console.log("txtOnKeyPress");
    }
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtWriter" runat="server" onkeypress="txtOnKeyPress()" />
```

<sub><sup>*</sup>Although, I did add `()` to the function name.</sub>

Regardless, if ASP.NET has an issue with that attribute name, you could simply attach a handler on the client-side. Depending upon your needs, the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event may make more sense. It's sort of a live [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event which fires as the input value is being edited (via keystroke, cut, paste, etc). Here's a sample:

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  console.log("value: %o", this.value);
});
```

```html
<input autofocus placeholder="type here"></input>
```

<sub>Note browser compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input#Browser_compatibility).</sub>

Now, the previous sample fires with every single change to the input value... which can be quite bit, i.e.: **4 times** for simply typing, "test". Since you'd (presumably) like it to trigger your server-side code, we'll want to wait for any changes made in rapid succession before actually posting the form:

```js
function __doPostBack(name, argument) {
  // dummy version of ASP.NET's __doPostBack  
  console.log("value: %o", document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value);
}

var t; // handle for our timeout
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  // input received... cancel the previous timeout, if any
  clearTimeout(t);
  // wait 1000 milliseconds (1 second) for more input before posting
  t = setTimeout(__doPostBack, 1000, this.name);
});
```

```html
<input autofocus placeholder="type here" name="test-input"></input>
```

<sub>See also: `window.setTimeout()`, `document.querySelector()`, `document.getElementsByName`, and `EventTarget.addEventListener()`.</sub>

In your code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack && Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == txtWriter.UniqueID) {
        GridView1.DataSource = /* some data source */;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: protected void txtWriter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var qry = from ct in  db.writerhistories.Where(o => o.fname.Contains(txtWriter.Text)) 
                      select new{
                          ct.fname,ct.lname ,ct.wid 
                          
                      };
            GridView1.DataSource = qry;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

Comment: this is my c# code . How can i use this in javascript function?